# make application use same timezone, regardless of user location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, timezone

I am writing an winforms application that is supposed to be used by users from multiple timezones on the same data files.
Part of the operations use timestamps and obviously I want those to be of the same time globally, say ZULU-time (GMT+0 without DST). For now it can be a hard-coded solution.
This seems like something to set globally, in the initialization of the application,
but I do not know where exactly to set this.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761933/net-defining-timezone-at-application-level) seems to be more about display of data, which is irrelevant here. I actually want everyone to see the same DateTimes round the globe.

Comment: Use UTC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @x... that generally does what I need. but I'd like to not have to think about this everytime I use "DateTime.Now" or similar. Is there no way to globally force this?

Comment: The UTC version of DateTime.Now is DateTime.UtcNow. "Now" is local time.

Comment: @x... so all I have to do, is use DateTimeUTC in place of DateTime on all occasions? Sound good!

Comment: Yes, and all over the world have always the same time, example: if you are in London, UTC is 10am. If you are in US, UTC is also 10am, if you are in Japan, UTC is also 10am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
DateTime.UtcNow
```

or

```
DateTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

later, if you want to local time, you can convert it to local time.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx